# Redirecting URL for product sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort my product lists into either Name or Price, I have a javascript function and a select/option bit of code to do it, but I want it to be as buttons rather than a dropdown.

```
<!-- A script to pick up the change event on the drop-down list below and redirect to the option selected's value. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', 'select[data-sort-redirect]', function(){
    path = window.location.pathname + '?' + $(this).val(),
    baseUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
    window.location = baseUrl + path;
    });
</script>
<!-- A drop-down list with hard-coded values.  -->
<select data-sort-redirect>
    <option id="1" value="orderBy=base_price&order=asc"{% if sortField == 'base_price' and sortOrder == 'asc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Price - Ascending</option>
    <option id="2" value="orderBy=base_price&order=desc"{% if sortField == 'base_price' and sortOrder == 'desc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Price - Descending</option>
    <option id="3" value="orderBy=name&order=asc"{% if sortField == 'name' and sortOrder == 'asc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Name - Ascending</option>
    <option id="4" value="orderBy=name&order=desc"{% if sortField == 'name' and sortOrder == 'desc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Name - Descending</option>
    <option id="5" value="orderBy=sku&order=asc"{% if sortField == 'sku' and sortOrder == 'asc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>SKU - Ascending</option>
    <option id="6" value="orderBy=sku&order=desc"{% if sortField == 'sku' and sortOrder == 'desc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>SKU - Descending</option>
    <option id="7" value="orderBy=created_at&order=asc"{% if sortField == 'created_at' and sortOrder == 'asc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Date Created - Ascending</option>
    <option id="8" value="orderBy=base_price&order=desc"{% if sortField == 'created_at' and sortOrder == 'desc'  %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Date Created - Descending</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible with this code to do this?

Comment: Whenever `document.location` is updated a browser will attempt to navigate to whatever the new value is. So, sort of *yes* but you would need to remove all of the cruft for the "`select`" function and convert it to a "`button`" function. Not to forget that the `select` itself would need to be converted to a list of `buttons`.

Comment: You just need buttons for name and price? not sku and date?